# Flask 405 POST Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, ajax, apache, web, flask

I'm developing a Web app; I got an error in browser console, after adding a new Python/Flask method that I call via Ajax:

**"POST 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)"**

I've found many similar questions here, but no answer worked:

- I specified both GET and POST methods for the route: `methods=['GET','POST']`
- I restarted apache
- I set dataType to "jsonp"

Several Python/Flask functions in the same file are already working in the same way, with no problem. Maybe Flask should be reloaded? configured with the new route?

Also, everything worked fine with my local server on my machine. It's only now that I'm porting the code to the hosting server that I got this issue.

**My JS**

```
function launchStreaming(jsonPath){
    var data = {};
    data.file = jsonPath;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/launchStream",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) {
            stringDebug('streaming Success!');
        },
        error: function(e) {
            stringDebug(e);
            alert ("Problem during streaming, please refresh and retry");
        }
     });
```

**My Python**

```
@app.route('/launchStream', methods=['POST'])
def launchStream():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_datas = request.json
        # do streaming...

        return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check there is any *uwsgi* service on production (ex. by *ps -aux*, try to find some line like *uwsgi --ini myproject.ini*). If you will find uwsgi restart it.

Comment: If this is iinfact a good answer please explain more as to why s/he should check and what s/he is finding out by following your instructions

Comment: Yes, there are _uwsgi_ services running. I restarted uwsgi, but nothing changed. I will check again soon. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10321066)

Comment: @ForceMagic I have reputation lower than 50 so I cant comment Charlie posts. 
Charlie please provide linux version, in my opinion there is problem with some service, you should check running services (ex. _service --status-all_).

Comment: @PawełKalinowski Yeah I know, but what can we do? Only flag it and a mod will put it as a comment. I don't like this system either.

Comment: @PawełKalinowski Thanks again. The server Linux version is redhat 4.9.2-6   I run your command and there are several services running. It seems OK on this part. How can I check if there's a problem on this side?

Comment: @Charlie Well I think there is some service that cache scripts on productions server. First I mind that can be uwsgi, but that can be also pypy (in this case project is compiled and the change dont affect the live version).

Comment: @PawełKalinowski Not sure we're using pypy, I'm going to check. Thanks again

Comment: We're not using pypy. We're not having this problem anymore, but now the video stream fails with a 502 Error. I'm opening a new question.